# How to access struct fields from list in a loop

Tags: go, struct

I am inserting a `struct` variable in the list. I am able to retrieve that inserted item in the loop but not the individual value. I am getting the error:

```
e.Value.name undefined (type interface {} is interface with no methods)
```

Code given below:

```
type Item struct {
    name  string
    value string
}
queue := list.New()
per := Item{name: "name", value: "Adnan"}
queue.PushFront(per)

for e := queue.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
    fmt.Println(e.Value.name)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[`container/list.List`](https://golang.org/pkg/container/list/#List) is not generic, it works with `interface{}`. Try to use a slice of type `[]*Item` or `[]Item`, so you won't have this problem.

If you must use `list.List`, you may use a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions):

```
fmt.Println(e.Value.(Item).name)
```

Using a slice it could look like this:

```
var queue []Item
per := Item{name: "name", value: "Adnan"}
queue = append(queue, per)

for _, v := range queue {
    fmt.Println(v.name)
}
```

Note however that `append()` appends to the end of the slice, so it's not equivalent with [`List.PushFront()`](https://golang.org/pkg/container/list/#List.PushFront).

Comment: Thanks for your helping and teaching something new, TypeAssertion. I'd go for it since I have to make a queue like structure so list is apt.